# Solve for $x, y \in \mathbb R$ - $\left\{ \begin{align} \sqrt x + \sqrt {y + 3} = 3\\ \sqrt{5 - x^2} + \sqrt y = 3 \end{align} \right.$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve the following system of equations for $x, y \in \mathbb R$ - $\left\{ \begin{align} \sqrt x + \sqrt {y + 3} = 3\\ \sqrt{5 - x^2} + \sqrt y = 3 \end{align} \right.$.

$(x \in [0, \sqrt 5], y \ge 0)$

Of course, we could go further and have that $$\sqrt x + \sqrt {y + 3} = \sqrt{5 - x^2} + \sqrt y \iff \sqrt{5 - x^2} - \sqrt x = \sqrt{y + 3} - \sqrt y \le \sqrt 3$$

$$\implies x \in \left[-\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt 3  - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{4\sqrt 3 - 3}, \sqrt 5\right]$$

Notwithstanding, it wouldn't help much.

Furthermore, we have that $$[(\sqrt{y + 3})^2 - (\sqrt y)^2] - (\sqrt{y + 3} + \sqrt y)(\sqrt{y + 3} - \sqrt y) = 0$$

$$\implies (3 - \sqrt x)^2 - (3 - \sqrt{5 - x^2})^2 - (6 - \sqrt x - \sqrt{5 - x^2})(\sqrt{5 - x^2} - x) = 0$$

$$\iff (\sqrt x - 1)\sqrt x(6 - \sqrt x - \sqrt{5 - x^2}) = 0 \iff \left[ \begin{align} \sqrt x - 1 = 0\\ \sqrt x = 0\\ 6 - \sqrt x - \sqrt{5 - x^2} = 0 \end{align} \right.$$

It needs to be proven that $6 - \sqrt x - \sqrt{5 - x^2} > 0$ for $\forall x \in [0, \sqrt 5]$, which I couldn't have in the three hour I was given in the competition.

$\implies \left[ \begin{align} x = 1\\ x = 0\\ \end{align} \right.$.

For $x = 1$, we have $y = 1$, and for $x = 0$, we have $y = 6$ and $y = \dfrac{\sqrt{10} - \sqrt 2}{2}$, which is, of course, illogical.

The only solution to the above system of equations is $x = y = 1$.

Is the above solution correct? How could I prove that $6 - \sqrt x - \sqrt{5 - x^2} > 0$ for $\forall x \in [0, \sqrt 5]$? And should you come up with any better solutions, please write them down below. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the above solution correct?

No, it isn't.

Note that $\sqrt{y+3}-\sqrt y$ is equal to $\sqrt{5-x^2}-\color{red}{\sqrt x}$, not $\sqrt{5-x^2}-x$.

More importantly,
$$(3 - \sqrt x)^2 - (3 - \sqrt{5 - x^2})^2 - (6 - \sqrt x - \sqrt{5 - x^2})(\sqrt{5 - x^2} - \color{red}{\sqrt x}) = 0$$
holds for every $x$ such that $x\in[0,\sqrt 5]$. (You can see by expanding LHS that LHS is a constant function which is equal to $0$.)

So, your method does not work.

---

Eliminating $y$, we get

$$(3-\sqrt x)^2-(3-\sqrt{5-x^2})^2=3$$
which is equivalent to
$$ -(5-x^2)+6\sqrt{5-x^2}-8+(x-6\sqrt x+5)=0$$
which can be written as
$$ (-\sqrt{5-x^2}+2)(\sqrt{5-x^2}-4)+(\sqrt x-1)(\sqrt x-5)=0$$
which is equivalent to

$$\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{2+\sqrt{5-x^2}}(\sqrt{5-x^2}-4)+\frac{x-1}{\sqrt x+1}(\sqrt x-5)=0,$$
i.e.

$$(x-1)\bigg(\underbrace{\frac{x+1}{2+\sqrt{5-x^2}}}_{\text{positive}}(\underbrace{\sqrt{5-x^2}-4}_{\text{negative}})+\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt x+1}}_{\text{positive}}(\underbrace{\sqrt x-5}_{\text{negative}})\bigg)=0$$

from which we get $x=1$ and $y=1$.